# Analysis of straight insertion

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, sorting

I'm currently reading through N. Wirths': Algorithms + Data Structures = Programs. I'm not sure, but I think there might be an error in the analysis of the provided straight insertion sort. Screenshot of the relevant paragraph is here: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2k387.jpg)

*Edit*: sentinel item `a[0] = x`, the current item that I want to insert at the appropriate place.

Sorry, another screenshot of relevant paragraph is here: [screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3hpQ.jpg)

```pascal
    type index = 0..n
    var a: array[0..n] of item

    procedure straightinsertion
        var i,j: index; x: item;
    begin
        for i := 2 to n do
        begin x := a[i]; a[0] := x; j := i-1;
            while x.key < a[j].key do
                begin a[j+1] := a[j]; j := j-1;
                end;
            a[j+1] := x
        end
    end
```

I think, that the analysis of the number of comparisons might be wrong. He claims, that the number `C_i` of key comparisons in the `i`-th sift is at most `i-1`. But shouldn't it be `i`? Because at the worst case, since we are using sentinel, we have to make an extra comparison with the sentinel too. I claim, that:

- `C_min = n-1`
- `C_ave = 1/4 * (n^2 + 3n - 4)`
- `C_max = 1/2 * (n^2 + n) -1`

The number of moves `M_i` should then be `(i-1)+2`. `M_min, M_ave, M_max` are, I believe, correct in the text (screenshot).

Could you please confirm if I'm right or is there something I'm missing?Thank you all very much!

Comment: What exactly is the sentinel defined as here? Also, does the author index arrays starting from 0 or starting from 1?

Comment: Sentinel is the current element that I want to sift/insert to the sorted part of an array. In this case, the arrays index start from zero.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but why would you compare the item that you wish to insert to itself?

Comment: I've edited my question - instead of me trying to rewrite it, I'll post another screenshot. Hope this might be better, sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** My apologies, misunderstood what you meant by sentinel earlier. It seems to me that you are correct, and this is indeed a typo. When you include comparison against the sentinel at $a[0]$, you perform $i - 1 + 1 = i$ comparisons on a worst case sift.

Comment: Well, let's say I have an array `[S,5,6,7,2,...]` where `S` is sentinel at position `0` and I currently want to insert the item `x=a[4]` (in this case the sentinel will be set to `S=7` since that was the last value that I inserted in). Now, `i = 4`, `S = 2` and `j = 3`. I will compare `2` (my item I want to insert) with all the other values -> `7, 6, 5` (that's 3 comparisons) but for the while loop to terminate (since for all the previous values `x<a[j]`, I have to make one more comparison with the sentinel `S` at position `a[0]`. So that's 4 comparisons.

Comment: Seems like you've answered your own question!

Comment: Thank you very much. It still seems weird to me, that the author would have then the `C_max` correct but `C_min` and `C_ave` wrong in his text: [authors' analysis](https://imgur.com/a/ni6onTP)